# Unity send value to UI Slider and update Slider bar

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, slider

I am pretty new to Unity and was wondering if you could answer this question. I know how i can get the value from the slider both via the script and through a function set in On Value Changed. However is it possible to send back a value to the slider and update the slider bar position in Unity?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Are you using the new Unity UI?

```
Using UnityEngine.UI;
```

Then you can use a public field to access the Slider

```
public Slider mSlider;
```

using Gameobject.Find is very slow so it is best to avoid that whenever possible. You can then assign your slider gameobject to this variable in the Editor.

Then in your Start or Update you can assign the value of the slider like this:

```
mSlider.value = 0.5f;
```

and the maximum value of your slider like this:

```
mSlider.maxValue = 1.0f;
```

Since the slider value is being set to half of the max value, your slider should be in the middle

Comment: Works great. Thank you :).

Comment: Glad to help. My first answer :D

Comment: Note to self, it is really important to pass float values to the Slider. If needed, cast values to float.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get the slider using GameObject.Find, you can set its normalizedValue property to update its position.

Note that GameObject.Find doesn't work on objects that aren't active in the scene, so you may have to grab it when the game starts and assign it to a variable which you can refer to later.